# How can I save a tensor of images as PNGs?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have a `tensor` that looks like:

```
Tensor("Identity:0", shape=(10000, 32, 32, 3), dtype=float32)
```

I figured out how to iterate over it:

```
for adv_x in tf.unstack(adv):
    asnumpy = tf.Session().run(tf.unstack(adv_x))
    print(asnumpy)
```

This returns:

```
...
Tensor("unstack:9997", shape=(32, 32, 3), dtype=float32)
Tensor("unstack:9998", shape=(32, 32, 3), dtype=float32)
Tensor("unstack:9999", shape=(32, 32, 3), dtype=float32)
```

How can I get the values of each and save to a png?

This is with `python3.7` and `tensorflow1.13`

I have an error:

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.FailedPreconditionError: Attempting to use uninitialized value conv2d_1/kernel
         [[{{node conv2d_1/kernel/read}}]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert it to numpy and then store it using `scipy.misc.imsave`

```py
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    asnumpy = sess.run(tf.unstack(adv)) # `asnumpy` stores images as numpy arrays
```

To store it:

```
import scipy.misc

for i, image in enumerate(asnumpy):
    scipy.misc.imsave('image' + str(i) + '.png', image)
```

Comment: My `adv_x` is a tensor with 10,000 elements. Would I continue to loop through it like I have?

Comment: `asnumpy` will store all your images. You can iterate over it as you did with `adv_x` tensor, but now `asnumpy` will store the actual values of your image.

Comment: `tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: assertion failed: [] [Condition x <= y did not hold element-wise:x (Variable/read:0) = ] [[[[158 112 49]]]...] [y (Cast_1/x:0) = ] [1]
         [[{{node assert_less_equal/Assert/AssertGuard/Assert}}]]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:`

Comment: for this one it is hard to say without actually looking at your code. Upload it somewhere and post here a link, I'll give it a try

Comment: https://github.com/shamoons/adversarial-cityscapes/blob/setup/cifar/cifar_attack.py

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191939/discussion-between-vlad-and-shamoon).